# Visual Studio Express 2012 can't add connection to Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure-devops, credentials, visual-studio-express

I was going to add a connection to Visual Studio Team Services, I entered the URL and clicked OK button and then this happened:[image: blank-page]

I waited for 1-2 mins, nothing or no event happened, it is still a white blank page. So I closed it and then this error appeared,[image: tf31003]

How to fix this? Or is it possible to put credentials on the link/URL?

Comment: What browser are you using? It looks like you're probably using an older version of IE's incompatible with Team Services.

Comment: i think so, what ie version is compatible?

Comment: IE11. Support was ended for IE9 and 10 earlier this year.

Comment: @newbieguy You need to upgrade your IE, I post an answer, you can check it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a modern browser. It looks like you're using an unsupported version of Internet Explorer -- VS Team Services supports IE11, nothing earlier.

Comment: how do i update? just download and install this https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer-11-for-windows-7-details.aspx ?

Comment: That would work. As would installing Chrome or Firefox or basically any modern browser.

Comment: @newbieguy What's the result if you access your VSTS via chrome?

Comment: is VSTS needed? i only have VS 2012 Express, i think it uses old version browser?

Comment: @newbieguy I mean access your Visual Studio Team Service instance (https://XXX.visualstudio.com) via chrome. Could you access it?

Comment: @newbieguy Do you set chrome as the default Browser https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95417?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en

Comment: @starain-MSFT although, its not chrome , im using slimjet (which is exactly like chrome but has a lot more features)  it should be fine, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This mostly happens if you don't enter correct user name and password or your user doesn't have access to TFS server.

1- Try login to TFS outside VS to see whether you have access, which eliminates the access issue if you have.

And you have to be in TFS security group based on [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/connect/connect-team-projects).

If none of these helps, try to run VS with admin privilege.

[image]

Comment: run as administrator? can't see `run as different user`

Comment: Can you get shift while right click to see if you see it?

Comment: im using VS express 2012, i dont have VSTS

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio uses IE and can't be changed to chrome, you can check [this](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/7175610-don-t-use-ie-exclusively-as-the-internal-browser) user voice, so you need to upgrade your IE to IE 11.

Comment: too bad i need new laptop (im out of space :( ) anyways i'll try this soon